# Changing option menu item in android fragment programmatically Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently trying to enable one menu item I have on my Options Menu and disabling another and vice versa when it's pressed. I don't quite know how this is done and every other attempt I've tried hasn't been successful.

Here's how my app is currently set up. I'm using a single activity and multiple fragments. My MainFragment has the following within it to set up the Options menu:

```
class MainFragment: Fragment() {
...
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        ...
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(binding.mfToolbar)
        ...
        
        return binding.root
    }

    ...

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.recycler_view_toggle_list -> {
                // TODO: Implement what happens here with the RecyclerView
                // Also disable this menu item and enable grid view item
            }
            R.id,recyclver_view_toggle_grid -> {
                // TODO: Implement what happens here with the RecyclerView
                // Also disable this menu item and enable list view item
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

menu_item.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.jre.projectcounter.ui.main.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_toggle"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_list"
        android:title="@string/list_view"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_toggle_grid"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_grid"
        android:title="@string/grid_view"
        android:visible="false"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

When I try to do the following within the `when` statement under `R.id.recycler_view_toggle_list`:

```
    binding.mfToolbar.menu[R.id.recycler_view_toggle_list].isVisible = false
    binding.mfToolbar.menu[R.id.recycler_view_toggle_grid].isVisible = true
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

What am I doing wrong or missing to get the options to switch between each other?

Comment: Do you know `ViewModel` and `LiveData`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `findItem` if you're using the id of item. Because when you do `menu[0]` it expects index & not id.

So in your case it should be something like this:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        when(item.itemId) {
            R.id.recycler_view_toggle -> {
                binding.mfToolbar.menu.findItem(R.id.recycler_view_toggle).isVisible = false
                binding.mfToolbar.menu.findItem(R.id.recycler_view_toggle_grid).isVisible = true
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I was one method away from being right... *facepalm* Thank you!